# Add columns for CSV output

Tags: powershell, csv

I have this PowerShell query listed below and I require the headers to be `machine, path, filewalkmethod`

```
$fs = Get-FileServer
foreach ($s in $fs) {
    foreach ($share in $s.Volumes) {
        ($s.Servername, $share.Share, $share.FileWalkMethod) -join "," |
            Out-File -Append D:\data\splunk\otl_varonis\otl_varonis_monitoring.csv
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
nas01e,E$,Windows
```

Updated Query I'm using:

```
Import-Module -Name VaronisManagement 
Connect-Idu 
$fs = Get-FileServer 
      foreach($s in $fs){
         $s.Volumes | Select-Object @{n='ServerName'; e={$s.ServerName}}, Share, FileWalkMethod |
         Export-CSV D:\data\splunk\otl_varonis\otl_varonis_monitoring_test.csv
            -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested but this should work:

```
foreach($s in $fs){
    $s.Volumes | Select-Object @{n='Machine'; e={$s.ServerName}}, Share, FileWalkMethod | Export-CSV D:\data\splunk\otl_varonis\otl_varonis_monitoring.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Note that the parameter `-Append` for `Export-Csv` was introduced with PowerShell v3. To make this compatible with earlier versions you could pipeline the loop:

```
$fs | ForEach-Object {
    $machine = $_.ServerName
    $_.Volumes | Select-Object @{n='Machine';e={$machine}}, Share, FileWalkMethod
} | Export-Csv D:\data\splunk\otl_varonis\otl_varonis_monitoring.csv -NoType
```

Comment: That did provide the headers in the output but only returned one value with it, there should be over 400 results.

Comment: @dcraven Edited to add `-Append`, like in your `Out-File`

Comment: Getting the below error:
       Export-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Append'.
At D:\Scripts\OTL_Monitoring.ps1:5 char:185
+     $s.Volumes | Select-Object @{n='ServerName'; e={$s.ServerName}}, Share, FileWalkMethod | Export-CSV D:\data\splunk\otl_varonis\otl_varonis_monitoring.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: What version of Powershell are you on? Also you can try -NoClobber instead of -Append

Comment: It says \system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe. That gave the same error also.

Comment: Please update your question to add the code that you are running now and the error that you are getting. This feels like a syntax error.

Comment: @dcraven All versions of PowerShell reside in that directory. From what I heard it's an artifact of when Microsoft considered parallel installations of different PowerShell versions (same as the `.ps1` extension). To identify the version of PowerShell you have installed enter `$PSVersionTable` in a PowerShell console. Most likely you're still on v2, since the `-Append` parameter for `Export-Csv` was introduced with PowerShell v3.